# How to serve html page and jaxrs in one spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs

I would like to have jaxrs endpoint in spring boot app.
On the same server I would like to have html page that servers RichInternetApplication with single page.

Is such configuration is possible?
I am trying, but it seems they work to exclude each other.

My mvn home controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeContoller {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and jaxrs conf:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // scan the resources package for our resources
        packages(getClass().getPackage().getName() + ".resources");
    }
}
```

And jaxrs endpoint

```
@Path("/") public interface Api {
    @GET @Path("ping") Response ping();
}
```

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class ApiController extends Application implements Api {
    @Override public Response ping() {
        return Response.ok("pong").build();
    }
}
```

If I would go with spring mvc instead of jaxrs it would work?

Please help

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: So To serve RIA You had to deploy 2 tomcat instances on production?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose one implementation. You cannot get both.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey

Comment: So serving simple html page using Spring MVC and @Controller with jaxrs is invalid?

Comment: @masterdany88 no that is fine.